# handling click event inside div using AJAX

Tags: ajax, dynamic, html

i am having side menu, where users clicks on links pages should load inside a div in the center of the page using `AJAx` requests and it's working properly, however when i click on a link inside the div itself, it loads the whole page, any one knows where is the problem

Ajax function:

```
function loadmypage(divID, pageURL)
{
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", pageURL ,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

links used:

```
<a href="javascript:loadmypage('1', 'ex.php')"></a>
```